# Where Oracle Network is loaded? On server on client memory

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial, oracle-spatial-ndm

When loading Spatial Network into memory **where is the actual memory occupied**? On client or server side?

*PS, example for loading network into memory:
PL/SQL:*

```
sdo_net_mem.network_manager.read_network(net_mem=>'XXX', allow_updates=>'TRUE');
```

*Java:*

```
NetworkMetadata metadata = LODNetworkManager.getNetworkMetadata(sql.getConnection(), 'XXX', 'XXX');
NetworkIO networkIO = LODNetworkManager.getNetworkIO(sql.getConnection(), 'XXX', 'XXX', metadata);
networkIO.readLogicalNetwork(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the LOD APIs the memory is allocated in the client side or where your client application is running. Please check this whitepaper: [A Load-On-Demand Approach to Handling Large Networks in the Oracle Spatial Network Data Model](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/spatial/pdf/ndmlod11gr2_wp_1009.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It's on the client (i.e. host application). If you're using PL/SQL then the database itself is the host application. If you're using Java and run your code on the application server then it's on the appserver.
A recommended approach is LOD. And in contrast to in-memory you can fine-tune, how big the partitions are and how many should be loaded in memory at once, so you have good control of the memory consumption. In-memory can be considered as a corner case of LOD with just 1 unlimited partition and everything loaded into memory.
The drawback of LOD is the necessity to partition your network.